# Cannot view my data in listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I wonder why the code inside the static can view the data such as item 1 in the list but when i put inside my asynctask function named onPostExecute().it cannot. This page is the android default layout that view the item data in listview and can see the details beside it too

```
package com.example.mobile_e_commerce.dummy;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.mobile_e_commerce.R;

/**
 * Helper class for providing sample content for user interfaces created by
 * Android template wizards.
 * <p>
 * TODO: Replace all uses of this class before publishing your app.
 */
public class DummyContent {

    /**
     * An array of sample (dummy) items.
     */
    private static final ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.example.mobile_e_commerce.webserviceurl");

    private final String NAMESPACE = rb.getString("WSDLTargetNamespace");
  private  final String SoapURL = rb.getString("SoapAddress");
   private final String SOAP_ACTION = rb.getString("SoapAction");
    private final String METHOD_NAME = rb.getString("OperationName");
    private final String NAMESPACE2 = rb.getString("WSDLTargetNamespace");
    private  final String SoapURL2 = rb.getString("SoapAddress");
     private final String SOAP_ACTION2 = rb.getString("SoapAction2");
      private final String METHOD_NAME2 = rb.getString("OperationName2");
      private final String NAMESPACE3 = rb.getString("WSDLTargetNamespace");
      private  final String SoapURL3 = rb.getString("SoapAddress");
       private final String SOAP_ACTION3 = rb.getString("SoapAction3");
        private final String METHOD_NAME3 = rb.getString("OperationName3");
        private final String NAMESPACE4 = rb.getString("WSDLTargetNamespace");
        private  final String SoapURL4 = rb.getString("SoapAddress");
         private final String SOAP_ACTION4 = rb.getString("SoapAction4");
          private final String METHOD_NAME4 = rb.getString("OperationName4");
          private int number = 0;
          private String myNumber = "";
    public static List<DummyItem> ITEMS = new ArrayList<DummyItem>();

    /**
     * A map of sample (dummy) items, by ID.
     */

    class NamedataLoader extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{



        //ProductCollection pc = new ProductCollection();
        //TextView textView = new TextView(pc);
         private String valuePass;
         PropertyInfo getInfo = new PropertyInfo();

     @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);





            request.addProperty("number", number);


            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(

            SoapEnvelope.VER11);

            envelope.dotNet = true;

            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SoapURL);
            Object response = null;          


                    try
                    {

                    httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                    response = envelope.getResponse();
                    valuePass = response.toString();//response.toString();//trying to get from my
                                              //webservices but url not found,solve it later
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception)
                    {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("Apps Error", exception.toString());
                    }
                    return valuePass;
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String tV) {

         try{
    //  TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Product1);
        //  textView.setText(tV.toString());
```

I add the addItem function here so that it can load the item in the current page as background task

```
             myNumber = Integer.toString(number);
             addItem(new DummyItem(myNumber,tV.toString()));
         }
         catch(Exception ee)
         {
             Log.e("App onDataLoader Error: ", ee.toString());
         }
     }
}



    public static Map<String, DummyItem> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<String, DummyItem>();

//The code here after comment can add to the listview//

        //static {
            // Add 3 sample items.
        //  addItem(new DummyItem("1", "Item 1"));
            //addItem(new DummyItem("2", "Item 2"));
        //  addItem(new DummyItem("3", "Item 3"));
        //}
```

The add item function

```
    private static void addItem(DummyItem item) {
        ITEMS.add(item);
        ITEM_MAP.put(item.id, item);
    }

    /**
     * A dummy item representing a piece of content.
     */
    public static class DummyItem {
        public String id;
        public String content;

        public DummyItem(String id, String content) {
            this.id = id;
            this.content = content;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return content;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: May be you need to refresh the list after adding data.

Comment: No///i think there something with the static that cover the addItem function that add Item 1,2,3